# String split and get particular string

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string:

```
 "cards_NNS may_MD be_VB worth_JJ hundreds_NNS a_DT report_NN"
```

Now i'm trying  to get those words in a string array from given string which has `_NNS and _NN and _JJ` at the end of word.

output:

```
cards worth hundreds report
```

what I have tried :

```
string.split("[^_NNS]+");
```

please give me some idea.

Comment: thanx for your valuable comment but i already tryied this its not working according to my requirment

Comment: regex `(\\w+(?=(_JJ)|(_NNS)|(_NN)))` will match what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**code**

```
String val = "cards_NNS may_MD be_VB worth_JJ hundreds_NNS a_DT report_NN";
String[] allVal = val.split(" ");
for(String each: allVal){
    if(each.endsWith("_NNS") || each.endsWith("_NN") || each.endsWith("_JJ")){
        System.out.println(each);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
cards_NNS
worth_JJ
hundreds_NNS
report_NN
```

**Edit**

**code**

```
String val = "cards_NNS may_MD be_VB worth_JJ hundreds_NNS a_DT report_NN";
String[] allVal = val.split(" ");
for(String each: allVal){
    if(each.endsWith("_NNS") ){
        System.out.println(each.substring(0, each.length() - 4));
    }else if(each.endsWith("_NN") || each.endsWith("_JJ")){
        System.out.println(each.substring(0, each.length() - 3));
    }
}
```

**output**

```
cards
worth
hundreds
report
```

Comment: Cut the *_ext* parts.

Comment: Thanx Gaurav!! can we remove _NNS _NN _JJ from output word mean wants only cards worth hundreds report.

Comment: It would be nice if you explain what is `ext parts` ??

Comment: Yes, you have substring() method for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` here:

```
String str = "cards_NNS may_MD be_VB worth_JJ hundreds_NNS a_DT report_NN";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)_(?:NNS|JJ|NN)\\b").matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

This will find all those sequence of words, which ends with `_NNS` or `_JJ` or `_NN`. Then the first capture group captures the string before `_`.

Comment: @RohitJain did you use regex here?

Answer (score 0):

This becomes a rather complicated regex if you want to do it in one split operation. Here is one working approach though:

```
String input = "cards_NNS may_MD be_VB worth_JJ hundreds_NNS a_DT report_NN";
String[] output = input.split("_(JJ|NNS?).*?(?=\\b(\\w*_(JJ|NNS?)|$))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
```

This prints

```
[cards, worth, hundreds, report]
```

The regex starts by finding a suffix that is `_JJ`, `_NN` or `_NNS`. Then it continues until it finds either a word ending in one of the mentioned suffixes, or the end of the string (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    String str = "cards_NNS may_MD be_VB worth_JJ hundreds_NNS a_DT report_NN";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+?)_(NNS|NN|JJ)\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

> cards
>  worth
>  hundreds
>  report